# SSH Reverse Tunneling

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, reverse-tunnel

I use this command to create a reverse tunneling from my home machine to an AWS instance, so that I can connect to my home machine from anywhere

```
ssh -R 5000:localhost:8000 aws_machine
```

However, when I execute this command on my home machine, it prompts for my password and logs into my AWS instance.

Edit: Got it to work using few extra parameters

```
ssh -g -f -R 5000:localhost:8000 aws_machine -N
```

Comment: That's as expected.  To create a tunnel, you have to have a connection from your machine to the remote machine . . . you may want to check the man page for ssh, as you'll likely the the `-g` option, and you may want to use the `-f` option.

Comment: @ernie. Thanks. To have a connection we can use -g

Answer (score 3):

That behavior sounds like expected behavior. To create a tunnel, you have to have a connection from your machine to the remote machine.  It sounds as if you want to create the tunnel, but not have a foreground SSH session.

I'd suggesting checking the man page for ssh, and you'll probably want to use

- -g this will allow for remote hosts to use the tunnel
- -f this backgrounds the SSH session after login (you'll need to search for the ssh command and kill it afterwards if you want to close the tunnel)
- -N you'll need to this to background the session, as -f expects a command